# Как получить порядковый номер символа по таблице Unicode

Tags: java

Скажите, как можно получить порядковый номер символа по таблице Unicode в Java? В Паскале была функция `ord(char)`, а какой аналог в Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас есть

```
char c = 'W';
```

то нужно сделать всего-лишь

```
int u = (int) c;
```

Результатом будет 87.